# Using a binomial random variable to get the number of objects needed

Tags: probability, random-variables

The problem goes like this, there are $n$ objects being transported. Each object has probability $p=0.15$ of being broken during transportation, independently of the other objects. How small should $n$ be so that the probability of having at least one object broken is less than $0.75$

My Process:

First I set up the equation for a binomial random variable:

$P(X=x) = \binom n x (0.15)^x (0.85)^{n-x} < 0.75$

This simplifies to:

$\binom n 1 (0.15) (0.85)^{n-1} < 0.75$

Which simplifies further to

$(n) (0.15) (0.85)^{n-1} < 0.75$

I'm struggling to see where to go from here, how do I determine the number of objects?

Answer (score 3):

You have written down $P(X=1)$.  This is the probability of having one object broken, it is not the probability of having **at least** one object broken.  We have
$$P(X\ge1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\binom n0(0.15)^0(0.85)^n\ .$$
Can you simplify this, put it less than $0.75$ and then solve?